Generic alternative for postgres specific json search
I have created a postgres specific sql with which I can succesfully search a json string value for a the label element. The json would look like this and is stored as a string in the db:
{"list":[{"label":"Label", "taskReference":"myReference",...}]}

The query I have created:
SELECT ELEM ->> 'label' 
FROM MY_TABLE
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(DATA::JSONB -> 'list') AS ELEM 
WHERE ELEM ->> 'taskReference' = 'myReference';

the result would be
Label

This is however postgres specific. The problem is that we don't always use the same database type depending on environment. Is there anyway to achieve the above with "standard" generic sql functions?

Since you used db-specific features, your code is tied to Postgre. The standard don't cover that, so if you want to ever support anything beyond Postgre your better option would be to do it client-side. Other db engines may have similar function with different syntax or may not have it at all.

Use the SQL/JSON path language. All databases that have support for this, can work with your application. Check your database manuals to see what is supported. See for example https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH

The same with SQL/JSON path language (standard SQL) using jsonb_path_query() - to be exactly equivalent to your query, returning a set of all matches from the same JSON document:
SELECT jsonb_path_query(data, '$.list[*] ? (@."taskReference" == "myReference")."label"')
FROM   tbl
WHERE  data @? '$.list[*] ? (@."taskReference" == "myReference")."label"'

Standard SQL does not allow set-returning functions like jsonb_path_query() in the SELECT list. You could move the function to the FROM list like in a LATERAL join like in your original. But it's typically more sensible to use jsonb_path_query_first() to quickly get the first match - like when you know there can only be one:
SELECT id
     , jsonb_path_query_first(data, '$.list[*] ? (@."taskReference" == "myReference")."label"') AS label
FROM   tbl
WHERE  data @? '$.list[*] ? (@."taskReference" == "myReference")."label"';

The added WHERE clause enables the use of a GIN index on the jsonb column in Postgres. Like:
CREATE INDEX tbl_data_gin_idx ON tbl USING gin (data jsonb_path_ops);

Essential for performance with big tables and selective queries.
Related:

Index for finding an element in a JSON array
Find rows containing a key in a JSONB array of records

Aside: To me, the biggest problem in your setup seems to be the use of different RDBMS. I would avoid that.

Thanks for the elaborate. I've learned something new :)
The jsonb_path_query function still seems to be Postgres specific though, as the equivalent oracle function seems to be json_query.
Furthermore the function accepts a jsonB so it seems in your example, you're missing a cast to jsonb from character varying.
finally, yes, using different RDBMS is not by my own choice. Could have made things a lot easier if we could get rid of it :D
